# List<double[][]> to List<double[]>

Tags: c#, arrays, flatten

I'm a python guy and have recently started a C# project. One part of my code takes a `myList = List<double[][]>` and needs to turn it into a `myNewList = List<double[]>` to pass to another function.

So suppose `myList` looks like this:

```
{{{0.0, 1.0}, {2.0, 3.0}}, {{4.0, 5.0}, {6.0, 7.0}}}
```

I want `myNewList` to look like this:

```
{{0.0, 1.0}, {2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0}, {6.0, 7.0}}
```

In python, I would do this:

```
myNewList = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(myList))
```

Now, I can very easily implement this with a `foreach` loop and keep `Add`ing to `myNewList`, but does anyone know of a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `SelectMany` to "flatten" lists. Basically if you have a list of lists, it will concatenate all the lists into one. In this case you have a `List<double[][]>` so it's nested three times.

```
  List<double[]> flattenedList = myList.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y).ToArray()).ToList();
```

Will do it for you. The first `Select` doesn't really do anything, I like to think of it like it's a for loop, read it as "for each x do x.SelectMany" it's needed to get down one layer to the `double[][]` elements since those are really what you're flattening.

Comment: This produces a 2 element list with 4 element arrays. It is not correct.

Comment: @lukegravitt Oh I see what you're saying... I guess I didn't look at the expected output closely enough. I'll revise the answer.

Answer (score 5):

better use `LINQ`:

```
var myNewList = myList.SelectMany(x=>x).ToList();
```

Comment: This will result in two arrays of length for, for the sample input.  The OP wants four arrays of length two.

Comment: This produces a 2 element list with 4 element arrays. It is not correct.

Comment: @Servy for the OP's requirement, I couldn't imagine the answer can be such simple as I updated (and also tested).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
myNewList.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y).ToArray()).ToList();
```

This will give you a `List<double[]>`.

Comment: I tried the code above in VS2012 and gives me the expected result. It gives me a list with 4 double[]. Maybe I don't get the question ???

Comment: +1 Tested this as well. It produces exactly the desired results.